# Function to make sure dividend is greater than divisor?

Tags: php, javascript, division

Hey just curious is there a function that you can use to divide in "the right order", so that the dividend is always the larger number? Currently I do this

```
x=5
y=10
z=0

if x>y{
z = x/y
}else{
z = y/x
}
```

I was just wondering if there was a function I could use to do this in one line, like

MakeSureDividendBigger(x/y)

type thing.

Thanks

Comment: There's no "the right order" for the general case.  Most calculations wouldn't make sense if you just arbitrarily flip the two operands around.

Comment: You can always create your own function...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
var z = Math.max(x, y) / Math.min(x, y);
```

Or a function:

```
function divideNice(x, y) {
    return Math.max(x, y) / Math.min(x, y);
}

var z = divideNice(x, y);
```

**PHP:**

```
$z = max($x, $y) / min($x, $y)
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand why it's the simplest answers like these that often get the most upvotes... not that I'm complaining. :)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is a special function for this, but possible one line solution is to use [ternary conditional operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php):

```
$z = $x > $y ? $x / $y : $y / $x;    // PHP

var z = x > y ? x / y : y / x;       // JavaScript
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm unfamiliar with the ? and :, what do they mean? And I can't google it.

Comment: It is called "ternary confitional operator". This is the same `if ... else`, but written in one line.

Comment: If the condition before the ? is true return the value before the : else return the value after the colon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.max` and `Math.min`.

```
Math.max(x,y) / Math.min(x,y)
```

- [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
- [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Or in Mozilla (Firefox) you can easily do a swap.

```
if(x < y)
   [x,y] = [y,x]

x/y
```

This is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29).

Comment: What do you mean by "in Mozilla"?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: I meant the JavaScript implementation of the Mozilla project, which is included in Firefox.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: I messed up the syntax. Updating.